# Sails js sessions not working with Microsoft Edge

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js, session-cookies, microsoft-edge

I inherited a site that does not work in Microsoft Edge. When trying to use ajax post requests, I would get 403 errors, CSRF token mismatch. Which is strange because I update them on each page load. After looking at request data on the server side, I noticed that all these sessions were being created. No cookies are being sent from the client, which would have the session id— which would have the matching CSRF token.

Here's what the request looks like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/main/doThing',
    method: 'POST',
    xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
    data: {stuff: 3, _csrf: csrf},
});
```

And the cookie settings:

```
cookie: {
    maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: false,
    path: '/',
}
```

The conclusion I've come to is that Edge is not sending session cookies to the server.

The weird part is that this works with every other browser I've tried (Chrome, Firefox, Safari). So would this be a browser issue? I'm not blocking cookies in Edge.

Has anyone run into a similar issue? Is it fixable? Or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you ever found a solution to this. I'm having similar problems, but they only seem to have started with Edge 15.

If you've found a solution an update would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a manual Windows 10 Update cured the issue for me. Previously my Edge was 42 and Copyright 2018. It is now 44 and Copyright 2019. Session cookies are sent as expected now.